# What jquery tables support table cell tooltips?

Tags: datatables

i need to display tooltips for my table cells. Are there any plugins for that purposes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any table and tooltip plugins you want - you just need to trigger the tooltips correctly depending on how you are initializing and updating the table.

For example, if you use jQuery DataTables (which I assume you are looking at given the tag you gave your question) with the jQuery UI tooltip widget you could simply initialize the tooltips once you've initialized the table. If you have the tooltip data already in the table, it could be as simple as:

```
$('#mytable').dataTable().tooltip();
```

If you have a more complex table that gets updated (such as using deferred rendering for a giant dataset), then you'd probably need to tie into the row creation callback to get the tooltips on any new rows by doing something like this in the init options:

```
        "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
            $('.tooltip', nRow).tooltip()
        }
```